# Using Top in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

A question on using `Top`. For example, we have this SQL statement:

```
SELECT TOP (5) WITH TIES orderid, orderdate, custid, empid
FROM Sales.Orders
ORDER BY orderdate DESC;
```

It orders return rows by orderdate first then select the top most five rows.
But isn't that `ORDER` clause happens after `SELECT` clause, which means that the first five order in random will be returned first then those five rows are ordered by orderdate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But isn't that `ORDER` clause happens after `SELECT` clause, which means
>   that the first five order in random will be returned first then those
>   five rows are ordered by orderdate ?

No. `ORDER BY` is processed after the `SELECT`, but limiting the result set to 5 rows happens even later.

The physical details of actual query processing may vary, but the end result would be as if the server sorted the whole table by `orderdate`, then picked the top 5 (or more if needed due to ties) rows, return those rows and discard the rest.

Answer (score 3):

The order of commands in the statement doesn't reflect the actual order of operations that SQL follows. See [this article](https://www.periscopedata.com/blog/sql-query-order-of-operations) which shows the order to be:

1. from
2. where
3. group by
4. having
5. select
6. order by
7. limit

As you can see, the TOP operation (limit) is the last to be executed.

Answer (score 1):

Question has already an accepted answer. But I would like to quote content from Microsoft Documentation.

[Logical Processing Order of the SELECT statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#logical-processing-order-of-the-select-statement)

> 1. FROM
> 2. ON
> 3. JOIN
> 4. WHERE
> 5. GROUP BY
> 6. WITH CUBE or WITH ROLLUP
> 7. HAVING
> 8. SELECT
> 9. DISTINCT
> 10. ORDER BY
> 11. TOP